# Testing java.util.prefs.Preferences void method with mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, preferences

I don't know how to test correctly void method with Preferences object inside, this is a method which I want to test:

```
public void setPersonFilePath(File file, ViewGenerator viewGenerator) {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(ViewGenerator.class);
    if (file != null) {
        prefs.put("filePath", file.getPath());

        // Update the stage title.
        viewGenerator.getPrimaryStage().setTitle("AddressApp - " + file.getName());
    } else {
        prefs.remove("filePath");

        viewGenerator.getPrimaryStage().setTitle("AddressApp");
    }
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
private FileManager fileManger;
private File file;
private ViewGenerator viewGenerator;
private Preferences preferences;

@Before
public void prepareDependencies() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    fileManger = new FileManager();
    file = mock(File.class);
    viewGenerator = mock(ViewGenerator.class);
}

@Test
public void test() {

    fileManger.setPersonFilePath(file, viewGenerator);
    verify(preferences).remove("filePath");
}
```

I've tried mocking preferences, as well as initializing preferences with new object inside test method.

Comment: Did you add `@Mock` annotation to `ViewGenerator viewGenerator` and `File file`?

Comment: Where is the call to `setPersonFilePath(..)`? Or are you testing `loadPersonDataFromFile(..)`?

Comment: Ok, now it's correct, I put wrong test. `setPersonFilePath(..)` is also in the `loadPersonDataFromFile(..)` and that's where mistake comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito can't mock static methods like `Preferences.userNodeForPackage()`.

My advice would be to wrap these static calls into a custom class `PreferenceManager`, and to inject an instance of `PreferenceManager` into the object under test.

You could then mock `PreferenceManager`, inject the mock, and make it return a mock `Preferences`.

Comment: So maybe I'll ask diffrent - what is the proper way to test such method?

Comment: Just as I said: refactor it to depend on a PreferenceManager, that can be mocked.

Comment: Ok, but what with i.e. `viewGenerator.getPrimaryStage()` - it's just a regular getter. It has been mocked and still It've got NullPointerException

Comment: Of course: you mocked it, so its `getPrimaryStage()` method returns null, unless you tell it to return something else.

Comment: Ok, got it. So to how to verify it, no matter whater it returns null or not (there is not Stage object also). Or is it totally wrong approach.

Comment: Create a Stage, configure the mock viewGenerator to return that Stage. Check that the Stage's title is AddressApp.